# Adding a media file to Wordpress: Can't seem to increase maximum file size

Tags: wordpress

We have our first Wordpress installation ever, and it works very well with little configuration.

For our first post, we have content that needs to be accompanied by a video, a roughly 9MB webm file. However, the maximum file upload size is 8MB. There's a message in the upload window stating that, and trying to upload a file larger than the displayed maximum size generates a message that the file is too large to be uploaded. The request doesn't seem to generate an entry in the Apache access log, which leads me to believe that it's a Javascript test.

Now, raising that limit shouldn't be a problem, and yet it is. I have tried most of the suggestions found on the net:

- php.ini or php5.ini with increased `upload_max_filesize`
- .htaccess with `php_value upload_max_filesize`
- increasing `upload_max_filesize` server wide from the system php.ini

I can confirm that the last point actually changed the system wide setting: Creating a phpinfo() type file inside the wordpress directory and running it from the web, the new value of 64M shows up. However, Wordpress still limits the uploads to 8MB.

I have grepped through the Wordpress installation for either `8M` or `8192`, and neither produce any line that sets this limit.

Of course, I can easily change the code of Wordpress to "solve" my problem, but with this solution comes the usual problem of having to redo this every time I install an update.

So, my question is :

How do you actually change the maximum size for media file uploads in a way that keeps my Wordpress installation upgradeable?

Answer (score 0):

Try the post_max_size php.ini setting [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size).

```
upload_max_filesize = 32M
post_max_size = 32M
```

Comment: Under either name `php.ini` or `php5.ini` in both root and wp-admin directory, the suggestion doesn't seem to change the Wordpress setting.

Comment: Post your access and error log entries for the upload, and maybe a couple of entries in either direction.

Comment: I'm not trying an upload, I'm looking at the number displayed in the media files upload window that displays the maximum file size for uploads at 8 MB.

Comment: I'm confused. In your last comment you said "I'm not trying an upload", but you're in the upload window, and in your question you indicate you want to upload content to Wordpress. Perhaps you could clarify the question. Also suggest you post the output of phpinfo() and the logs I suggested.

Comment: I am determining that the 8 MB upload limit exists by opening the file upload dialog from within the Wordpress administration and reading the message `Maximale Dateigröße für Uploads: 8 MB.`. Trying to upload a larger file, the page responds with the message `HANEU__2015.mp4 überschreitet das Upload-Limit.`, while there is no corresponding entry in either `error_27_06_2016.log` or `httpsd_27_06_2016.log`.